# What is `^M` and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: vim, special-characters

When I open the file in Vim, I see strange `^M` characters.

Unfortunately, the world's favorite search engine does not do well with special characters in queries, so I'm asking here:

- What is this `^M` character?
- How could it have got there?
- How do I get rid of it?

Comment: It's a control character digraph, for more info:  `help digraph-table`.

Comment: VS Code has an EOL option at the bottom that will auto convert an open file.

Comment: @StackUnderflow when using VSCode, changing the line endings to LF when working on linux files helps. I use WSL ...A Windows file like $profile has no problem with Linux file ending LF. Maybe Win beats Linux here.

Comment: My situation is, I was developing my project on Windows, later I ran a Linux virtual machine, and by sharing folders, I directly opened the project that was originally on Windows in the Linux virtual machine. When I ran `git status`, a large number of files were listed, and each line of these files ended with `^M`. I solved this issue with the following two commands.

Comment: git status -s | grep "^ M" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs dos2unix

Comment: git status -s | grep "^ M" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs git add

Answer (score 231, accepted):

The `^M` is a carriage-return character.  If you see this, you're probably looking at a file that originated in the DOS/Windows world, where an end-of-line is marked by a carriage return/newline pair, whereas in the Unix world, end-of-line is marked by a single newline.

Read [this article](http://peterbenjamin.com/seminars/crossplatform/texteol.html) for more detail, and also the Wikipedia entry for [newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

[This article](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format) discusses how to set up vim to transparently edit files with different end-of-line markers.

If you have a file with `^M` at the end of some lines and you want to get rid of them, use this in Vim:

```
:s/^M$//
```

(Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to insert that `^M`.)

Comment: Try `:%s/^M/\r/g` instead to remove `^M` and replace `^M` with newline character `\r`. Without `%`, the command applies for current line only. And I came across some examples where `^M` is not at end of line, such as `The first line.^MThe second line.`

Comment: Or if you don't want loads of line breaks you could just do `:%s/^M/`

Comment: If it's just a carriage return by itself, that might be the classic (pre-Unix) Macintosh line break. Even some newer programs like Excel 2007 for Mac do that for some reason.

Comment: @larsks But https://www.altap.cz/salamander/help/salamand/appendix_txtfiles/ says that `^M` is used in UNIX

Comment: The article to which you have linked says that `\n` is used in Unix, which is correct.  That is ASCII code `10`, otherwise known as `^J`.

Comment: Not sure if it's something in my vim config, but I have to type `Ctrl+Q`, then `Ctrl+M` to get that character to generate!

Comment: I seem to get this character when I enter it in AWS lifecycle configurations. How do I get rid of it considering I am entering code in the cloud?

Comment: For newbies, the s means substitute, after the first slash follows the pattern which says `^M` as the last character($). Substitute with nothing as seen after the second slash. Here `^` is not the beginning of the line, but part of the special char M.

Comment: Debian (and possibly other dists) uses this character too, at least for /var/log/apt/term.log.

Comment: for what it's worth, ctrl-q is required if you have the ms windows configuration that makes ctrl-v paste

Comment: @BradParks you are probably using (sourcing) `mswin.vim`. It's the default on Windows.

Comment: This answer seems incorrect - `:s/^M$//` searches for a line beginning and ending with `M`. What is displayed in VIM as `^M` is actually a carriage return `\r`. To remove all occurrences the command is: `:%s/\r//`.

Comment: I sometimes meet these trailing carriage returns in some text files even if the file was (correctly) loaded by VIM in DOS mode. The problem seems to be, that there's either a lone CR at the end of the line (Macintosh line break as @sudo has suggested) or better yet, a sequence of CR CR LF, i.e. there's an extra CR before a DOS line break. How does this come up? Well apparently some oddball broken software can produce this. Also note that "CR only" is the canonical line break encoding in serial terminals, and captures can contain this. I just got this from Whois for Windows by Sysinternals.

Comment: E486: Pattern not found: ^M$

Answer (score 111):

A simpler way to do this is to use the following command:

```
dos2unix filename
```

This command works with path patterns as well, Eg

```
dos2unix path/name*
```

If it doesn't work, try using different mode:

```
dos2unix -c mac filename
```

- **`-c`** Set conversion mode. Where CONVMODE is one of: `ascii, 7bit, iso, mac` with `ascii` being the default.

Comment: +1 for mentioning about the -c flag default value and other options. At first try, the default didn't have the expected results. With `dos2unix -c max` it worked.
`dos2unix: converting file launch_me.sh to Unix format...`

Comment: Amazing little utility. For ubuntu just `apt-get install dos2unix`. If you need to use it recursively you can refer to this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929461/how-can-i-run-dos2unix-on-an-entire-directory I foolishly ran it on every directory manually and only thought to look up after the fact.

Answer (score 109):

This worked for me

```
:e ++ff=dos
```

*The :e ++ff=dos command tells Vim to read the file again, forcing dos file format. Vim will remove CRLF and LF-only line endings, leaving only the text of each line in the buffer.*

then

```
:set ff=unix
```

and finally

```
:wq
```

Comment: thanks! this worked for me but the accepted solution didnt

Comment: Does `ff` refers to file format? What about `++ff`?

Comment: The :e ++ff=dos command tells Vim to read the file again, forcing dos file format. Vim will remove CRLF and LF-only line endings, leaving only the text of each line in the buffer.

Comment: To learn about ff, execute ":help ff"

Comment: simple and effective. I am not sure why cat  file1 >> file2 is introducing dos line feeds when file 1 didn't have it in the first place

Comment: great solution thank you

Answer (score 49):

Most UNIX operating systems have a utility called `dos2unix` that will convert the CRLF to LF. The other answers cover the "what are they" question.

Answer (score 22):

Sed in-place solution without needing to type the special character (you can copy this and it works):

```
sed -i -e "s/\r//g" filename
```

Explanation:

```
-i: in-place
-e: regular expression
\r: escaped carriage return
/g: replace globally
```

Comment: The questioner was already editing the file with VIM, note.  And there has been an in-place `sed` answer here since 2012.

Comment: Yeah, but a good, working solution was missing. The existing sed solution doesn't work out-of-the-box.

Comment: Dale Hagglund's in-place `sed` most definitely _does_ work out of the box.

Comment: Well, not for me. I'm on Ubuntu LTS 18.04.

Comment: Make sure that you read the _whole_ answer.

Comment: This helped me out editing a file on Alpine Linux from a Windows desktop that would count Ctrl M as a line return, making the above answers ineffective.

Comment: created a file ending with `-e` but worked

Answer (score 13):

Another way to get rid of carriage returns is with the `tr` command.

I have a small script that look like this

```
#!/bin/sh
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
tr -d '\r' <"$1" >"$tmpfile"
mv "$tmpfile" "$1"
```

Answer (score 9):

You can clean this up with `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/^M$//' < infile > outfile
```

The trick is how to enter the carriage-return properly.  Generally, you need to type `C-v C-m` to enter a literal carriage return.  You can also have sed work in place with

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/^M$//' infile
```

Comment: doesn't work (macOS)

Comment: @Dorian Which part? The basic structure of the sed script is almost certain to work, but entering the literal CR (^M) depends on which terminal program you're using, and I don't know anything about Mac's in that regard.

Comment: @Dorian To figure out what's not working, start by replacing the ^M with, eg, a capital A, and see if the sed command strips a final A from its input lines. If no, you're getting your basic sed syntax wrong somehow; if yes, you're having trouble correctly typing the single CR character into the shell.

Comment: sorry I don't have the file to test it anymore, not sure, maybe it's because I use fish, maybe sed is different on macOS, etc.

Comment: @Dorian No idea about fish, but I'm pretty sure you could create your own test file of one or two lines.

Comment: @Dorian See also Dream Flasher's solution with a less tricky way to type CR

Comment: Sed is usually different on Mac, try using homebrew to install `gnu-sed` and use the command `gsed`.

Answer (score 5):

**What is this ^M?**
The ^M is a carriage-return character. If you see this, you're probably looking at a file that originated in the DOS/Windows world, where an end-of-line is marked by a carriage return/newline pair, whereas in the Unix world, end-of-line is marked by a single newline.

**How could it have got there?**
When there is change in file format.

**How do I get rid of it?**
open your file with

```
vim -b FILE_PATH
```

save it with following command

```
:%s/^M//g
```

Comment: You've got a typo in _open your filr with_.

Comment: This answer does not add anything to the other answers. The first paragraph is an almost verbatim copy from the accepted answer. The given code will not _save_ anything, but just _remove_ all carriage return characters from all lines. And I am not sure how opening the file in binary mode will help here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -bsc '%s/\r//|x' file
```

1. `-b` binary mode
2. `%` select all lines
3. `s` substitute
4. `\r` carriage return
5. `x` save and close

Answer (score 2):

In my case,

Nothing above worked, I had a CSV file copied to Linux machine from my mac and I used all the above commands but nothing helped but the below one

```
tr "\015" "\n" < inputfile > outputfile
```

I had a file in which ^M characters were sandwitched between lines something like below

```
Audi,A4,35 TFSi Premium,,CAAUA4TP^MB01BNKT6TG,TRO_WBFB_500,Trico,CARS,Audi,A4,35 TFSi Premium,,CAAUA4TP^MB01BNKTG0A,TRO_WB_T500,Trico,
```

Comment: `mac2unix -n inputfile outputfile`, or, equivalently, `dos2unix -c mac -n inputfile outputfile` will handle that situation.

Answer (score 2):

I have to dissent from all the answers here - what VIM displays as `^M` is the carriage return character from DOS/Windows. To remove it from all lines in VIM the command is:

```
:%s/\r//
```

Trying to remove `^M` with a regex like `s/^M//` means you don't understand regex - `^` just means the start of the line and `^M` matches any line starting with capital `M`.

Comment: Note that at least [two](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32024/170373) [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32003/170373) (including the now top one) say to enter that `^M` with Ctrl+V Ctrl+M, telling the software to enter it as a literal. It's not the same as entering a circumflex and the letter M.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your ~/.vimrc

```
command! Tounix :call Preserve('1,$s/^M//')
```

Then when you have a file with the Windows line endings, run the command ":Tounix".

Answer (score 0):

If your file uses mixed line breaks, i. e. `\r\n` and `\r`, you can use this `sed` script (this is an all-in-one solution and of course, you can also use it if your file merely has `\r\n` or `\r` line breaks):

`sed -i[SUFFIX] ':read; N; $!b read; s/\r\n/\n/g; s/\r/\n/g' file`

`-i` tells `sed` to replace your file with the result of the script,
and if you supply a `SUFFIX`, a backup will be created with that suffix.

You also may omit `-i` and redirect the output to an arbitrary file.

**How the script works:**

Special commands:

- `N`: Adds a newline to the pattern space, then appends the next line of input (with any trailing `\n` removed) to the pattern space.
- `$!`: Don't execute the following command on the last line.
- `b`: Branches unconditionally to the specified label.

So when the cycle starts (we have just one cycle here), `sed` reads the first line of input, removes any trailing `\n` and places it in the pattern space, then it processes the script:

`N` adds a newline to the pattern space, then appends the next line of input (with any trailing `\n` removed) to the pattern space.
This is repeated until the last line is reached, then the substitutions operate on the pattern space, which contains the whole file *as a single line*, which is the reason why we need the `g` flag for the substitutions.

The first substitution replaces each `\r\n` with `\n`.
After this, the remaining ("lonesome") `\r`s are replaced with `\n`.

**Why do we need the `N` loop?**

Since `sed 's/<regexp>/<replacement>/[flags]' file` reads a line from the file, performs the substitution on it, prints the result, reads the next line and so on, `\n` cannot be used within the `<regexp>` part.

But if we have the whole file as a single line in the pattern space, we will be able to use `\n` within the `<regexp>` part, and this is necessary to distinguish between the sequence `\r\n` and "lonesome" `\r`s.

**Example:**

```
$ sudo file /var/log/apt/term.log
/var/log/apt/term.log: UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF, CR, LF line terminators, with escape sequences, with overstriking
$ sudo sed -i.bak ':read; N; $!b read; s/\r\n/\n/g; s/\r/\n/g' /var/log/apt/term.log
$ sudo file /var/log/apt/term.log
/var/log/apt/term.log: UTF-8 Unicode text, with escape sequences, with overstriking
```

Answer (score -3):

In the past, I have seen even configuration files are not parsed properly and complain about whitespace, but if you vi and do a set list it won't show the whitespace, grep filename [[space]] will show you ^M

that's when `dos2unix file` helps

Comment: This answer does not bring nothing new, does2unix is already mentioned at least in two answers much more older.