# command not found error after giving permission to access file using chmod

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ksh, chmod

I've been trying to run a script using `chmod`.

Here's how I tried to execute the script:

```
$ chmod u+x tester
$ ./tester
./tester: Command not found.
```

I always get the Command not found error and I'm struggling to figure out why. Tried the full path fix too and run `chmod` from there but still it won't solve the problem.

I used `ls -l tester` and here's my access permission:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kplus user123 983 Jan 28 15:00 tester
```

Here's the complete version of the Linux that I am using:

```
Linux KODRL58IRA02 2.6.18-308.e15 #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 17:17:51 EST 2012 x86_64
```

Here's the script that I am trying to run:

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo ""
echo " = K+WA =";
WA_PORT="`cat /home/kptp4/testdirectory2/kondor.active |grep PORTAL_PORT|cut -d '&' -f 2`"

#== Checking Tomcat of WebAccess
printf "%25s" Tomcat
touch /home/kptp4/processiddirectory/tomcat-*.pid
PID=`cat /home/kptp4/processiddirectory/tomcat-*.pid`
if  [[ $PID = "" ]];then
echo " x 0"
else
PSPID=`/bin/ps -eo pid | grep -w $PID`
if [[ $PSPID -eq $PID ]];then
/bin/ps -ef | grep $PID | grep -v grep | awk 'NR==1 {print " = "$8 $9 $10 $11 $12 $13 $14 $15}'
else
echo " x 0"
fi
fi

PORT_STATUS=`netstat -an | grep ${WA_PORT} | grep LISTEN | perl -pe "s/^.+\n/LISTENING/g;"`
PORT_STATUS=${PORT_STATUS:="NOT LISTENING!!!"}
echo " Port ${WA_PORT}/TCP = ${PORT_STATUS}"

cd /home/kptp4/WebAccessFolder
(PATH=/home/kptp4/testdirectory/checkall.sh;) | perl -pe "s,^, ,g;"
echo ""
```

I've also tried to run it using `ksh`, `bash`, `sh` but no luck...

```
$ bash tester
: Permission denied

 = K+WA =
: Permission denied
: Permission denied
tester: line 29: syntax error: unexpected end of file
$ sh tester
: Permission denied

 = K+WA =
: Permission denied
: Permission denied
tester: line 29: syntax error: unexpected end of file
$ ksh tester
tester[2]: ^M: cannot execute [Permission denied]

 = K+WA =
tester[4]: ^M: cannot execute [Permission denied]
tester[6]: ^M: cannot execute [Permission denied]
tester: line 10: syntax error at line 29: `if' unmatched
```

Right now I'm wondering why I cannot run this script as I am able to run other scripts using the permission commands I have used above(`chmod u+x filename`). Any idea how I can solve this? This script is working fine in my SunOS version of Linux by the way, and I am wondering why it doesn't execute properly in this system.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It might hurt some people at Oracle if you call SunOS a "version of Linux". ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your script file has DOS/Windows line endings, e.g. Carriage Return (`^M`, chr(13)) in addition to the Line Feed character. The output `tester[2]: ^M: cannot execute [Permission denied]` certainly looks like that. This would also explain why the file cannot be executed by the shell directly: It is looking for an executable named `/bin/ksh^M` extracted from the shebang line, which most probably does not exist.¹

You should first try to find out if this is the case, e.g. by opening the file in an editor that shows the line endings or using `file tester` or even `od -ah tester`. Many editors can remove the CRs, as can the utility `dos2unix`. Under Windows, the Notepad++ editor is capable to convert line endings using the menu entry `Edit` -> `EOL Conversion` -> `UNIX/OSX Format`.

See also [What is `^M` and how do I get rid of it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32001/43377).

---

¹ *SuSE Linux used to have a funny symlink from `/usr/bin/perl^M` to `/usr/bin/perl` to allow all those random Perl scripts retrieved from the Web to work even without converting them to Unix line endings.*

Comment: Hi I used notepad++ to see if the file has DOS/Windows line endings, what showed up after every line in the my script is the CR LF.. does this confirm that my file has DOS/Windows line endings? thank you

Comment: @Francis Yes,  CR LF (Carriage Return - Line Feed) are DOS/Windows line endings. Unix/Linux uses LF only. You should be able to convert the file in Notepad++ using `Edit` -> `EOL Conversion` -> `UNIX/OSX Format`. I added this to my answer.