# find and sed (find and delete)

Tags: shell-script, sed, find, csv

I have a folder with few subfolders and files inside it. Also there is a CSV file containing the names of the subfolders and patterns that is there in the files inside the subfolder.

What I want to do is to read the CSV file using while loop inside the main folder and delete the matching patterns files using `sed`. I am using this `bash` shell script in Unix:

```
IFS=","
while read f1 f2
do
 find $f2/ -name vcs*.pv -exec sed -i '/$f1/d' {} +
done > export.csv
```

Error:

```
find: 'ap01\r/': No such file or directory.
```

CSV file:

```
S2AEC67X1,ap01
```

It is reading the `f2` value properly but not doing the rest.
I am keeping the CSV file inside the main directory which contains all the subfolders.

Comment: `done > export.csv` --> `done < export.csv`

Comment: If you got the `ap01` from the `export.csv` file to the script for processing, then you didn't use the `> export.csv` redirection. Post the script you actually used.

Comment: sorry about the mistake. Code :                                                         IFS=","
while read f1 f2
do
 find $f2/ -name vcs*.pv -exec sed -i '/$f1/d' {} +
done < export.csv

Comment: Is find needed here? Wouldn’t just calling sed directly work, with “$f2/vcs*.pv”?

Comment: @Guy Yes, if all files were within that top directory.

Answer (score 1):

This: `ap01\r`

Indicates that there is a [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) after the string `api01`. Try to remove that from the CSV file.

Update: also please read the comment from @RomanPerekhrest. You will want to change the `>` into a `<` in your `while` loop (if indeed you should even *use* a `while` loop, but that's another discussion entirely!).

Comment: The quoting is a mess as well (it will potentially apply filename expansion to the `-name` pattern but will pass `$f1` literally to `sed`)

Comment: @steeldriver Aye. Agreed.

Comment: @maulinglawns i removed the CR and now the error is :                         find: `ap01/': No such file or directory.

Comment: if i manually run the command putting the values directly it works fine, like: find ap01/ -name vcs*.pv -exec sed -i 'S2AEC67X1/d' {} +

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with the code and input file in this question:

1. The input file obviously have trailing carriage returns (`\r`) on each line.  This is probably due to hit having been created on a Windows machine as a DOS text file.  The usual way to get rid of these carriage returns is to run `dos2unix` on the file. See, for example, the question [What is `^M` and how do I get rid of it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it)
2. All variable expansions should be double quoted. In your command you use `$f2` unquoted as a path name to a directory. This would fail if `$f2` contains spaces.
3. Single quotes stops the shell from expanding a variable, which means that your `sed` script is looking for lines matching the literal regular expression `$f1`.  This regular expression will never match as the `$` will only match at the end of a line, and there will be no line that ends *and then contains the characters `f1` on the same line*. Double quoting the `sed` editing script will make the shell expand the `$f1` variable before invoking `sed`.
4. The pattern `vcs*.pv` is supposed to be an argument to the `-name` option of `find`, but since it's unquoted it would expand to any name in the current directory that matches that globbing pattern.  So if you had a file in the current directory whose name was `vcs-test.pv`, `find` would be invoked with `-name vcs-test.pv` and you would only ever find files with that name.  If you had several matching names in the current directory, you would cause `find` to complain about unknown options.
5. The `export.csv` file is outputted to (and emptied before any output from the loop happens). You would want the loop to read from it. This involves changing `>` to `<`.

The script, corrected:

```
while IFS=',' read f1 f2; do
    find "$f2" -type f -name 'vcs*.pv' -exec sed -i "/$f1/d" {} +
done <export.csv
```

I have also added `-type f` to the `find` command line as we probably do not want to accidentally pick up directory names. I have also made it so that the `IFS` variable is set *only* for the `read` command.

---

This is a variation on the above in the case that all files are located *directly* below the top directory whose name you are reading from the CSV file:

```
while IFS=',' read dir pattern; do
    for name in "$dir"/vcs*.pv; do
        test -f "$name" && sed -i "s/$pattern/d" "$name"
    done
done <export.csv
```

The good thing with this is that you get rid of `find`. The bad thing is that you now have one invocation of `sed` per file (usually not an issue unless you have hundreds or more files).

The following is a variation on the above that deletes lines depending on the *string* read from the CSV file.  The difference is that the pieces of code above all interpret the pattern as a *regular expression*, not as a fixed string.  This matters if your string contains characters that are interpreted a "special" in a regular expression, such as `.`, `*`, `[`, `]` etc.

```
while IFS=',' read dir string; do
    for name in "$dir"/vcs*.pv; do
        [ ! -f "$name" ] && continue
        grep -v -F -e "$string" "$name" >"$name.tmp" && mv -f "$name.tmp" "$name"
    done
done <export.csv
```