# How to remove error in cent os7 while using ansys 18.2 ic engine module

Tags: centos

I am using Ansys 18.2 (Ansys IC Engine (fluent)) in CentOS 7. I am adding `valve.prof` (a profile file) before opening the Ansys Design Modeler. However, during the decomposition step I get this error message:

> All lift valves are zero. Check valve lift profile format. TIP: Try using dos2unix command to convert the file to unix format.

I've only worked on Windows before; what does this mean? How do I use `dos2unix` here?

Comment: I'm voting to put on hold as unclear but I have a suspicion that this question will help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32001/237982

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message asks you to run `dos2unix` on (presumably) the `valve.conf` file since it may be a DOS text file. Unix text files have an ever so slightly different format from DOS text files and many programs that expects Unix formatted text files have issues reading DOS text files properly.

To install `dos2unix` on CentOS, if it is not already installed, open a terminal window and type the command

```
sudo yum install dos2unix
```

(this assumes that you are allowed to use the `sudo` command to execute things as the root administrative superuser).

Then, to hopefully fix the error, you would run the command

```
dos2unix valve.conf
```

(assuming that the file is located in the current directory).