# Create folders and subfolders from csv/txt file

Tags: bash, directory, mkdir

I have a excel file which i will convert to csv or txt file with following data:

```
ALFA ROMEO > 147 > Scheinwerferblenden
ALFA ROMEO > 156 > Scheinwerferblenden
ALFA ROMEO > 156 > Kühlergrill
AUDI > 80 B3 > Heckspoiler
.
.
```

and so on

I need to create folders and subfolders based on this data with following syntax:

```
├───ALFA ROMEO
│            ├───147
│            │     └───Scheinwerferblenden
│            └───156
│                  ├───Scheinwerferblenden
│                  └───Kühlergrill        
│
└───AUDI
       └───80 B3
               └───Heckspoiler
```

I tried to write mkdir -p bash scripts but with no success.

Comment: Is it a csv or is it separated by `>`s?  Does it also have the whitespace?

Comment: Now its excel separated by " > " (It have also whitespace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the input you have provided I was able to accomplish this with the following command

```
while read -r dir; do mkdir -p ./"$dir"; done< <(sed 's@ > @/@g' input)
```

You can replace `./` with the directory path you would like the directory tree to start in, if not the current directory.

This uses `sed` to convert your input lines from something like:

```
ALFA ROMEO > 147 > Scheinwerferblenden
```

to:

```
ALFA ROMEO/147/Scheinwerferblenden
```

Then it feeds this output to a while loop that uses `mkdir -p` to create the directory tree.

```
$ cat input
ALFA ROMEO > 147 > Scheinwerferblenden
ALFA ROMEO > 156 > Scheinwerferblenden
ALFA ROMEO > 156 > Kühlergrill
AUDI > 80 B3 > Heckspoiler
$ while read -r dir; do mkdir -p ./"$dir"; done< <(sed 's@ > @/@g' input)
$ tree
.
├── ALFA\ ROMEO
│   ├── 147
│   │   └── Scheinwerferblenden
│   └── 156
│       ├── K\303\274hlergrill
│       └── Scheinwerferblenden
├── AUDI
│   └── 80\ B3
│       └── Heckspoiler
└── input

9 directories, 1 file
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine except that it adding ? mark on all lowest level folders

Comment: I'm not sure what would cause that, perhaps there is something strange in your input file?  If the file was created on windows have you run it through `dos2unix` or something similar?

Comment: i have mac os, input file csv

Comment: Mac has a similar issue, you should run the file through mac2unix which comes with the dos2unix package if you brew install it.  Or check out this question [What is `^M` and how do I get rid of it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it)

Comment: Thanks Man! This was ^M issue. I edited file via vim and get rid of problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this, based on your input (using [*bash parameter expansions*](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)) :

```
while IFS=">" read -r c1 c2 c3; do
    c2=${c2% }
    mkdir -p "${c1% }/${c2# }/${c3# }"
done < file-or-input
```

### Output :

```
$ tree AUDI ALFA\ ROMEO/
AUDI
└── 80 B3
    └── Heckspoiler
ALFA ROMEO/
├── 147
│   └── Scheinwerferblenden
└── 156
    ├── Kühlergrill
    └── Scheinwerferblenden

7 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: Thanks, also works fine except that it adding ? mark at the end of name on all lowest level folders