# How to rename tar.gz files based on their match in the text file

Tags: files, rename, filenames

I have many tar.gz files in a folder on my Linux machine and also text file with tar.gz file names and matching sample names.

```
Current_directory
      |_______TDF.tar.gz
      |_______DFG.tar.gz
      |_______GHY.tar.gz
```

names.txt file which is in current directory looks like below:

```
Tar.gz_filenames       Sample_Names
DFG.tar.gz                Sample2
TDF.tar.gz                Sample1
GHY.tar.gz                Sample3
```

So, based on their match I want the following output in my Current_directory.

```
Output:

Sample1.tar.gz
Sample2.tar.gz
Sample3.tar.gz
```

I tried like following but didn't work:

```
for j in .tar.gz ; do
  sed "s/\(\w\+\)\s\+\(\w\+\)/mv '*_\1$j' '*_\2$j'/e" names.txt
done
```

Small update in my question: When I used this command `cat -e names.txt` I see like following:

```
Tar.gz_filenames    Sample_Names^M$
DFG.tar.gz  Sample2^M$
TDF.tar.gz  Sample1^M$
GHY.tar.gz  Sample3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way assuming no whitespaces is there in files name:

```
$ xargs -n2 echo mv -i <<<"$(sed '1d; s/$/.tar.gz/' names.txt)"
mv -i TDF.tar.gz Sample1.tar.gz
mv -i DFG.tar.gz Sample2.tar.gz
mv -i GHY.tar.gz Sample3.tar.gz
```

In `sed '1d; s/$/.tar.gz/'`, the `1d` is deleting very first line of the input fileName `names.txt` then the `s/$/.tar.gz/` adds `.tar.gz` in the end of every line (the `$` ponits to the end of line).

In `xargs -n2` we are reading two set of strings which separated with Space/ or Tab.

**Notes:**

- Based on output of `cat -e names.txt` your that file is not Unix type end-of-line format, to convert it to Unix type do `dos2unix fileName` then apply the above command to rename.
- remove `echo` for dry-run.

link to [What is `^M` and how do I get rid of it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32001/72456)

Comment: Hi, what if I have many columns in the names.txt file and "TAr.gz_filenames" is 8th column and "Sample_Names" is 9th column. How to give the command? It would be great if you could explain a little about your command. Thanq

Comment: I have updated my answer including explaining the command. _`"what if I have many columns in the names.txt file and "TAr.gz_filenames" is 8th column and "Sample_Names" is 9th column. How to give the command?"`_: this is also possible either with `sed` or `awk` or `cut` or ... to select those columns and feed to `xargs`. I see no such reason and difficulties shows that's different than what you asked already and got answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your names never have whitespace and that your `names.txt` file has a header on the first line as you show, you can do:

```
tail -n +2 names.txt | while read old new; do
    mv -i "$old" "$new"
done
```

The `tail -n +2` will print all lines of the file starting from the 2nd, so it will skip the header. Then, the `-i` option for GNU `mv` tells it to prompt you before overwriting an existing file (just in case there is a name clash).

Answer (score 0):

Using the shell: I assume that the tarfile names don't contain spaces and the sample names don't contain spaces:

```
{
    read header
    while read -r tarfile sample; do
        if [[ -f "$tarfile" ]]; then
            echo mv "$tarfile" "$sample.tar.gz"
        fi
    done
} < names.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

One `sed` command should be enough, given that input file format:

```
sed '1!{s/^/mv /;s/$/.tar.gz/e}' names.txt
```

---

Demo, without the `e`:

```
sed '1!{s/^/mv /;s/$/.tar.gz/}' names.txt
```

Output:

```
Tar.gz_filenames       Sample_Names
mv TDF.tar.gz                Sample1.tar.gz
mv DFG.tar.gz                Sample2.tar.gz
mv GHY.tar.gz                Sample3.tar.gz
```