# Grep a string in a file in bash

Tags: bash, grep

When I grep a string in a file, it gives me a match. However, when I do it in a bash script, it doesn't work.

```
$ cat files_android.txt
000d07dfe5016314c98b869c19c7f986b5db57db49ac76d16a5d2f5861a35072
001c738f74acbf19e3f31c09f6017de99bf3009a0b6f889740da0302ad172472
0047423956b09dd56a8b9c917d8f3028ad32ee01efdd501afa11b0777f4c184f
$ grep  000d07dfe5016314c98b869c19c7f986b5db57db49ac76d16a5d2f5861a35072 android.txt
G:\000d07dfe5016314c98b869c19c7f986b5db57db49ac76d16a5d2f5861a35072 - a variant of Android/Gappusin.C trojan
```

However, with the following script that read the string from the first argument and grep that in the second argument, no match is reported.

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
FILE1=$1
FILE2=$2
counter=0
for line in $(cat $FILE1); do
  echo "$line"
  if grep $line $FILE2; then
    counter=$((counter+1))
    echo "$counter"
  fi
done
echo "counter=$counter"
$ ./script.sh files_android.txt android.txt
000d07dfe5016314c98b869c19c7f986b5db57db49ac76d16a5d2f5861a35072
001c738f74acbf19e3f31c09f6017de99bf3009a0b6f889740da0302ad172472
0047423956b09dd56a8b9c917d8f3028ad32ee01efdd501afa11b0777f4c184f
counter=0
```

What is wrong with that?

[UPDATE]

Thanks to Stephen Harris, the root was that the files were saved in `dos` format. So `dos2unix` conversion fixes the issue.

Comment: Are you using cygwin or Windows Linux?  If so, ensure the file is in Unix format and not DOS format, because you might have hidden `^M` characters at the end of the `files_android.txt`

Comment: @StephenHarris that's most certainly the case. The only way I could reproduce OP's problem was by adding `\r` at the end of each line of `files_android.txt`.

Comment: In `vim`, I see `"android.txt" [dos] 1268L, 171482C ` and that `dos` also exists in `files_android.txt`. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes `[dos]` means it's in DOS format, so has the extra `^M` character.

Comment: But `vim` doesn't show any `^M` with blue/cyan color.

Comment: See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32001/237982

Comment: Please try and write this up as an answer, so other people searching will find useful results  (these comments may get lost).

Comment: [Don't read lines of a file with a `for` loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: If you just want to count the lines in `android.txt` that match the entries in `files_android.txt`, I'd suggest `grep -Fcf files_android.txt android.txt`

Comment: @mahmood you might be interested in combining the `-F` and `-f` options for `grep` to make your script a one-liner.

Comment: @steeldriver: I think that counts all instances however my script counts only one match which is what I want. To total number of lines in files_android.txt is 1172 and my script returns 974 while `-Fcf` returns 1256.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what is wrong with your code but it's possible that something is being expanded in an undesirable way due to unquoted variables.

I have made the following improvements:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE1=$1
FILE2=$2
counter=0

while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
    if grep -q "$line" "$FILE2"; then
        printf '%d\n' "$((counter++))"
    fi
done <"$FILE1"
printf 'counter=%d\n' "$counter"
```

---

1. Using bash to iterate through a file isn't ideal but if it is to be used, you should use a `while read` loop rather than a `for` loop.
2. `grep -q` is being used to suppress any output grep may produce
3. `printf '%d\n' "$((counter++))"` is being used to save a line
4. All variables have been quoted.
5. `printf` rather than `echo` is technically more portable but mostly a matter of preference.

Comment: The problem was with dos/unix file saves. Using `dos2unix` conversion program, my script as well as your script work fine. Thank you

Comment: `((counter++))` is not equivalent to `counter=$((counter+1))`.  The former would cause the shell to exit under `set -e` if the result was non-zero, whereas the latter would not.  The return codes are different.

Comment: To read the lines **exactly** (i.e. with leading/trailing whitespace intact), use `IFS= read -r line`

Comment: @mahmood Does this answer work with the dos lines?

Comment: @Xen2050: No it doesn't work with dos lines.

Comment: I wonder why... the $line you're grep'ing for must have a ^M at the end? So a modified $line, or grep command, might work...

Comment: @Xen2050:  Likely the loop wouldn't iterate over the file properly because there are no unix line endings.

Comment: @Jesse_b I tried duplicating the problem files on linux, using `unix2dos`, and I think I've got a solution... just having problems typing the special dos `^M` character in a bash script without using a hex editor (it's `0d`,  followed by a LF `0a`, I think)... any ideas to get bash to recognize it? Maybe something like `\0x0d`? -- I think I found it `\r`, carriage return (in man bash). I can't answer anymore, but using `read -r -d \r line...` should work. (I don't think this Q should have been marked duplicate really, unless they *wanted* to modify the files & not keep as-is)

Comment: Actually `read -r -d \r` didn't work, but `tr -d "\r"` did, I edited that in instead