# Command for converting rows to CSV file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, osx, text-formatting

I have a file of the format, with a leading space before each line:

```
 "Western Overseas",
 "Western Overseas",
 "^",
 "--",
 "^",
 "--",
 "--",
 null,
 24995,
 9977,
 "CR",

 "Western Refrigeration Private Limited",
 "Western Refrigeration Private Limited",
 "[ICRA]A",
 "--",
 "[ICRA]A1",
 "--",
 "Stable",
 null,
 14951,
 2346,
 "CR",
```

I would like to convert it to a CSV file with format:

```
 "Western Overseas","Western Overseas","^","--","^","--","--",null,24995,9977,"CR"
 "Western Refrigeration Private Limited","Western Refrigeration Private Limited","[ICRA]A","--","[ICRA]A1","--","Stable",null,14951,2346,"CR"
```

I'm trying to use `tr` but am having trouble since it either prints all output to one line and seems to replace newlines with a double newline. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: (1) Edited to reflect two lines instead of 3. (4) There are no leading spaces on the empty line, only at the beginning of lines with actual text.

Comment: No space. I.e. `foo,bar` is required for the output.

Comment: Please provide the first few lines of a hexdump from the actual file. Something like `xxd test.txt | head -n 12`.

Comment: ```00000000: 2022 5765 7374 6572 6e20 4f76 6572 7365   "Western Overse
00000010: 6173 222c 0a20 2257 6573 7465 726e 204f  as",. "Western O
00000020: 7665 7273 6561 7322 2c0a 2022 5e22 2c0a  verseas",. "^",.```

Comment: `awk  '$1=$1' RS=',\n\n' infile` if you don't mind last comma for last line.

Answer (score 5):

An awk solution is

```
awk '{if(NF){gsub(/^ |,$/,""); printf c $0; c=","}else{printf "\n"; c=""}};END{printf "\n"}'
```

expanded with comments:

```
{
    if(NF) { # if the line isn't empty
        gsub(/^ |,$/,""); # remove the first space and last comma
        printf c $0; # print the line (without a newline)
        c="," # set c to add a comma for the next field
    } else {
        printf "\n"; # empty line, output a newline
        c="" # don't print a comma for the next entry
    }
};
END {
    printf "\n" # finish off with a newline
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<file sed '
   :start
   s/\n$//
   t
   s/\n //
   N
   b start
  ' | sed 's/,$//'
```

The first `sed` loops (`:start`, `b start`) and appends lines to its pattern space (`N`) until a newline at the very end is found and deleted (`s/\n$//`). This indicates an empty line was read, the tool exits the loop then (`t`). At each iteration any surviving newline (and a consecutive space) is removed anyway to concatenate lines (`s/\n //`).

The second `sed` removes trailing commas.

Comment: This returns the same output as my input, without any commas.

Comment: I used `<test.txt` where that is the file in question, and made no other changes to your command.

Comment: I'm currently on MacOS, not quite sure what the `sed` differences might be between us. I repeated the test by copying the text as you did and have the same result.

Comment: @user362513 My `sed` is GNU sed, I guess yours is not. Please try the current version of my code. Any difference?

Comment: There appears to be a '^M' carriage return in my actual file. Do you have any idea how to get around that?

Comment: @user362513 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32020/108618

Comment: @user362513 Oh, I deliberately asked for the output of `xxd` to rule out this possibility. You gave me one with proper UNIX line endings (`0a`) and no `^M` (would be `0d`). Strange.

Comment: I was able to fix it by changing to `^M` using your code. All works now!