# Append a string to every line in a text file using sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression, macos

I have a txt file that contains a couple thousand dates. I would like to add a string to every line using osx bash. It works just fine in subline using regex but I can't get it to do what I want in bash - even using the same regex.

I figured SED is the right tool, added -E to get proper regex, then set 'select' every line  and add 'whatever' to the end of it. However - sed is replacing the first letter of the line instead of appending it to each line. Any clue why that might be?

```
sed -E 's/^(.*)$/\1whatever/g' testbase.txt
```

Thanks in advance for any hint - I'm looking forward to my 'aha' moment.

mi

add:
I did all my testing on a file that contains an email list (figuring text is text) instead of the file with the dates. Using the following command kindly provided by a commenter (thanks a lot!), I get the correct results (date, then whatever) in the date/time file. However - in the email list, I get a list of emails and between every line it adds another line with 'whatever'.

```
sed 's/^\(.*\)$/\1whatever/g' testbase1.txt
```

Here's the output of od -c datetimefile

$ od -c datetimefile.txt
0000000    a   b   r   c   o   o   k   i   e   3   @   g   m   a   i   l
0000020    .   c   o   m  \r  \n   d   i   c   o   o   k   i   e   3   @
0000040    a   o   l   .   c   o   m  \r  \n   p   o   r   c   o   o   k
0000060    i   e   7   6   @   g   m   a   i   l   .   c   o   m  \r  \n
0000100    t   e   r   c   o   o   k   i   e   4   @   g   m   a   i   l
0000120    .   c   o   m  \r  \n   s   u   m   c   o   o   k   i   e   l
0000140    1   1   @   g   m   a   i   l   .   c   o   m  \r  \n   n   l
0000160    c   o   o   k   i   e   0   @   g   m   a   i   l   .   c   o
0000200    m  \r  \n   m   c   d   c   o   o   k   i   e   2   @   h   o
0000220    t   m   a   i   l   .   c   o   m  \r  \n   a   n   d   r   c
0000240    o   o   k   i   e   a   1   1   @   g   m   a   i   l   .   c
0000260    o   m  \r  \n   c   a   c   o   o   k   i   e   @   e   l   l
0000300    e   r   v   i   k   .   d   k  \r  \n   n   a   v   e   c   o
0000320    o   k   i   e   r   d   1   @   g   m   a   i   l   .   c   o
0000340    m  \r  \n   f   a   r   i   a   c   o   o   k   i   e   1   0
0000360    @   g   m   a   i   l   .   c   o   m  \r  \n   y   o   c   o
0000400    o   k   i   e   o   e   4   0   1   @   y   a   h   o   o   .
0000420    c   o   m  \r  \n   a   n   d   c   o   o   k   i   e   r   e
0000440    n   2   3   @   g   m   a   i   l   .   c   o   m  \r  \n   c
0000460    o   o   k   i   e   k   a   7   7   @   h   o   t   m   a   i
0000500    l   .   c   o   m  \r  \n   l   i   l   c   o   o   k   i   e
0000520    8   8   @   a   o   l   .   c   o   m
0000532

output of od -c emaillistfile

$ od -c testbase1.txt
0000000    2   0   2   0   -   1   2   -   2   4   2   1   :   3   2   :
0000020    4   4  \n   2   0   2   0   -   1   2   -   2   4   2   1   :
0000040    3   2   :   4   4  \n   2   0   2   0   -   1   2   -   2   4
0000060    2   1   :   3   2   :   4   4  \n   2   0   2   0   -   1   2
0000100    -   2   4   2   1   :   3   2   :   4   4  \n   2   0   2   0
0000120    -   1   2   -   2   4   2   1   :   3   2   :   4   4  \n   2
0000140    0   2   0   -   1   2   -   2   4   2   1   :   3   2   :   4
0000160    4  \n   2   0   2   0   -   1   2   -   2   4   2   1   :   3
0000200    2   :   4   4  \n   2   0   2   0   -   1   2   -   2   4   2
0000220    3   :   2   6   :   0   1  \n   2   0   2   0   -   1   2   -
0000240    2   4   2   3   :   2   6   :   0   1  \n   2   0   2   0   -
0000260    1   2   -   2   4   2   3   :   2   6   :   0   1  \n   2   0
0000300    2   0   -   1   2   -   2   4   2   3   :   2   6   :   0   1
0000320   \n   2   0   2   0   -   1   2   -   2   1   0   1   :   4   9
0000340    :   3   4  \n   2   0   2   0   -   1   2   -   0   8   0   1
0000360    :   3   9   :   0   6  \n   2   0   2   0   -   1   2   -   1
0000400    0   1   1   :   4   7   :   4   3  \n   2   0   2   0   -   1
0000420    2   -   1   5   1   5   :   3   0   :   3   2  \n   2   0   2
0000440    0   -   1   2   -   1   5   1   6   :   0   2   :   5   6  \n
0000460    2   0   2   0   -   1   2   -   1   9   1   6   :   3   5   :
0000500    4   8  \n   2   0   2   0   -   1   2   -   1   9   2   1   :
0000520    5   8   :   1   1  \n   2   0   2   0   -   1   2   -   2   0
0000540    1   5   :   4   0   :   5   2
0000550

Comment: As you can see, the problem was caused by the carriage returns `\r`. I'm trying to find a duplicate target. Meanwhile you can solve your problem by running `dos2unix` (or see https://stackoverflow.com/q/800030) on the files before applying Sed to remove the carriage returns.

Comment: Actually, something like `sed "s/$/whatever/"` is pretty much enough to append AFAIK.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is \`^M\` and how do I get rid of it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it) Check the second answer `dos2unix filename`

Comment: Solved! Thank you so much guys! - I ended up running dos2unix first to get rid of \r in the files and then both the suggestions from quasimodo and d4rio worked great. Thank you!