# Grep not working inside for loop

Tags: bash, grep

So I want to use grep with variables I'd be picking from a text file (one per line). I've tried different commands for grep and it's not working... I've seen also similar questions, but anything seems to be working? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks. Below my attempt, manually assigning the variable hey grep works, but not if I attempt to take the variable from the ids.txt file

Thank you very much!

```
$ head ids.txt 
Nitab4.5_0005105
Nitab4.5_0007510
Nitab4.5_0001604
$ for i in $(cat ids.txt); do   grep -A1 "$i" seqs.fasta; done
$ hey="Nitab4.5_0001604"
$ grep -A1 "$hey" seqs.fasta
>Nitab4.5_0001604
ATGTCATGCATTTTTTAAAANNNNNNNNNNNA
```

Comment: Wrong line endings in the file? See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32001/108618).

Comment: Please also add an example of the `seqs.fasta` file that you're grepping from. I also suggest to add `echo` to the beginng of your `grep` command in your loop, to ensure the command actually looks the way you think it does. And last thing, please run the following command: `head ids.txt | cat -A` to check if there are any imvisible escape characters as @KamilMaciorowski suggested.

Comment: `grep` can read patterns from a file: `grep -f ids.txt seqs.fasta`. Also note, that `.` is a special character for regex pattern. You might want to use `-F` to advice `grep` to use a fixed string instead.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, indeed "^M" at the end of the lines. Working now. Thanks for your time. dos2unix fixed the issue