# VIM shows ^@ every other character and ^M^@ at the end of line

Tags: files, vim, unicode, character-encoding

Sorry if it's answered somewhere, I have no idea how to look for it. I received a series of reports from a bank that I'm supposed to process and they seem to be... badly encoded?

First two lines in VIM:

```
     1 ^M^@
     2 ^@:^@2^@0^@:^@3^@0^@4^@0^@7^@1^@9^@^M^@
```

Same two lines in e.g. gedit:

```
     1 
     2 :20:3040719
```

Anyone can tell me what's going on? It doesn't matter if I open the file with `fenc=utf8` or `fenc=cp1250` (which is the encoding these files were supposed to be encoded with). I even tried `fenc=ucs-bom` because I thought it has something to do with endianness but it doesn't change anything either. I know `^@` is null and `^M` is Windows style new line (CRLF) but changing between `ff=dos` and `ff=unix` doesn't matter either.

I have an older file from the same bank (before some changes they've introduced) and it works fine - `file` shows it's `extended-ASCII` while the broken file is shown as `data`:

```
$ file *sta
20220411_182719.sta: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
20220412_071916.sta: data
```

I can replace those characters in VIM and process the file then but I need to automate this process for thousands of files a day with PHP and can't really use VIM. Ideally I'd like to just tell the bank support what they've messed up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is \`^M\` and how do I get rid of it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it)

Comment: What does the `file` command report? For a data file called `fromthebank.dat` the command would be `file fromthebank.dat`

Comment: Added `file` output.

Comment: @jesse_b No, it doesn't answer my question. I want to process files in PHP, so I need to know what's going on. The ^M itself can be replaced but it doesn't tell me what they've broken.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, found it. It's `UTF-16 Little Endian`.

```
:e ++enc=utf16le
```

I can convert it properly now while processing.